# Why does <anonymous> appear in this stack trace?

Tags: javascript

Why does `<anonymous>` appear in this stack trace? Every object and function in the script has a name, so what is anonymous about it?

The script:

```
function weAllHaveNames(cb) {
  cb();
}

weAllHaveNames(function iHaveAName(){ var x = y.a; });
```

The stack trace:

```
weAllHaveNames(function iHaveAName(){ var x = y.a; });
                                              ^
ReferenceError: y is not defined
    at iHaveAName (/Users/Trindaz/code/scratchpad/funcs.js:5:47)
    at weAllHaveNames (/Users/Trindaz/code/scratchpad/funcs.js:2:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Trindaz/code/scratchpad/funcs.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: Node puts the file content inside a wrapper function. Maybe that function is anonymous? https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js#L441